# Added class back when length of ".class" < 6

Tags: jquery

I have an issue which is the following, I have multiple blocks like this:

```
<div class="form-input-wrap hidden">
    <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="opifer_form_post_valueset_namedvalues_naam_2_value" class="control-label ">Naam persoon 2</label>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Naam persoon 2" class="inputs form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <span class="fa fa-minus-circle"></span>
    </div>
```

As you can see they have class `hidden` when they are all on class shown the plus sign has to disappear and when not it has to appear simple is that!

I create something like this:

```
$('.fa-plus-circle').click( function() {

    if($('.show').length == 6) {
        console.log('6');
        $('.fa-plus-circle').removeClass();
    }else {
        console.log('5');
        $('.fa-plus-circle').addClass();
    }

});
```

Here is a screenshot to create a better view:

[image]

And here everything is set to `show`:
[image]

As you can see the class is removed but not added back when the length is less than 6.

Can somebody help me out on this issue?

Here is an fiddle:

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/4844/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify what class to Add/Remove in your methods.

You're doing `$('.fa-plus-circle').removeClass();` which removes all the classes from that element. Then you're trying to add it back with `$('.fa-plus-circle').addClass();` which doesn't add any class as you haven't specified what class to add.

Instead do:

```
$('.fa-plus-circle').click( function() {

    if($('.show').length == 6) {
        console.log('6');
        $('.fa-plus-circle').removeClass("hidden");
    }else {
        console.log('5');
        $('.fa-plus-circle').addClass("hidden");
    }

});
```

Comment: It is hidding but it will not display again

Answer (score 0):

You need to toggle visibility of elements `.fa-plus-circle` based on condition:

```
$('.fa-plus-circle').click( function() {
    $('.fa-plus-circle').toggle($('.show').length == 6);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lol sorry guys was messing with the wrong click function the answer is like this:

```
 $('.fa-plus-circle').click( function() {
      if($('.show').length == 6) {
          console.log('6');
          $('.fa-plus-circle').addClass('hidden');
    }
});

 $('.fa-minus-circle').click( function() {
    if( $('.hidden').length >= 3) {
        console.log('>3');
        $('.fa-plus-circle').removeClass('hidden');
    }

});
```